# Unable to upgrade PHP version on the Debian (Google Compute Engine)

Tags: linux, debian, php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to update PHP for my WordPress website on Google Compute Enginee, but I get un-expected errors. I've followed [this guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-php-on-debian/) and [this too](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19490/upgrade-php-to-73-unmet-dependencies)

To update my PHP version  to 7.4 but with no success. I have had a lot of difficulties with this already and it is frustrating, since I've tried a lot of solutions I find online and none seems to work.

Here is my environment:

> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Debian
> Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
> Release:        9.13
> Codename:       stretch

Here are the errors I get when I try updating:

After adding the ppa repositories, and updating with apt, I then ran `sudo aptitude install php7.4`

Then I'm prompted that additional dependencies are needed, that I should confirm with y(yes)/n(No)...
When I select yes, my OS returns me this :

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

And it ends there !!! is there something wrong with Google cloud's Debian OS on Compute Engine?

I tried another approach, which was to install each of the missing dependencies in a command as follows:

```
sudo apt install php7.4 php7.4-common php7.4-cli libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-fpm php7.4-cgi php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline
```

But I get this other error, stating me that some packages are virtual, and cannot be installed:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211 but it is not installable
                         Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: apache2 but it is not installable
```

Can someone help? This has been holding me back for some time already. And solutions online won't help.

Comment: In my experience the best way of dealing with this is not to upgrade PHP but rather 100% completely uninstall PHP from your server and then start from scratch. Your WordPress site will be down, but this is the cleanest and simplest solution. And unless your WordPress site uses some really crazy PHP settings (rare) everything should be 100% fine in the end using this approach.

Comment: Wordpress is off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill The post is not about WordPress but upgrading the PHP version in a Debian install. I see it as 100% valid. The addition of info about WordPress helps because at the end of the day, knowing the requirements of WordPress makes it easier to say what I said in my comment: Just uninstall PHP completely and reinstall the desired version.